# Firebase Cloud Messaging on flutter not calling onResume method

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried to implement FCM on flutter (testing on IOS) as per the instructions in the doc using the [firebase_messaging plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging), version: 5.1.8

In my flutter code I have called the onConfigure method with onMessage, onResume and onLaunch.

I am able to receive the push message when the app is already open, thus considering that all the configurations are proper.

But, when the app is in Background I don't seem to receive any callback in onResume method, neither onLaunch gets called.

When I open my app again onMessage is invoked.

I am using XCode:11 and tested on iPhone 8 & 11 simulator.

Thanks